# Passing 'this' inside a subexpression

Tags: express, handlebars.js, templating

Currently, I am using the #each helper to loop over an array. This array serves the purpose to pass information create list items with my document

`const categories = ['fruit', 'vegetables', 'dairy']`

```
  {{#each categories}}
         <option value="{{this}}" {{optionSelected product.category (this) }}>{{this}}</option>
  {{/each}}
```

I'm using the *optionSelected* custom helper to toggle the selected attribute on option

```
hbs.handlebars.registerHelper('optionSelected', function (test, option) {
    return test === option ? 'selected' : '';
})
```

The code as written doesn't work. If wanted to compare the `product.category` to a current iteration on the categories array defined above, how can I do that?

Comment: I think you need to step up an evaluation context or two in order to access your `product` object. The exact path will depend on the shape of your data, but it will look something like `../product.category`.

Comment: I can access the product object just fine within the context I'm in. My issue is that within my each block  I'm trying to pass each current iteration into my custom helper function as an argument.  Can I not pass the keyword "this" as an argument?

Comment: You can _definitely_ pass `this` to a helper. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to specify *what* isn't working about the code above.

As it is, it looks fine to me except for two things:

1. When you are within the context of the `#each` there is no `product` object on which to lookup `category`, so you will need to use a path to a higher evaluation context, like `../product.category`.
2. There is no need to wrap the `this` within the `optionSelected` call in parentheses. In fact, in my testing it seemed that the parentheses caused a compiler error.

The following is a perfectly valid template:

```
{{#each categories}}
    <option value="{{this}}" {{optionSelected ../product.category this}}>{{this}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/b93sfxr0/) for reference.

Comment: Your solution worked. I think wrapping my head around why it worked. Thank you.